# How to keep onclick function after page refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage, session-storage

I am new to javascript and trying to write a code where two different buttons give the page two different styles, so that you can select one design in the beginning and the site stays that way. How do I make it so that the design stays that way after refreshing the site/clicking a different page on the same site?

I have tried sessionStorage and localStorage, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

This is what I have so far:

```
function greenButton() {
 document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundColor = "white";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
 function redButton() {
  document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="green" onclick="greenButton()>green</div>
<div class="red" onclick="redButton()>red</div>

<div class="container">Content</div>
```

What do I have to change/add for the selected design to be active even after refreshing/switching pages?

Comment: You should show your attempt at using localStorage and explain how it didn't work. You should be saving the backgroud color when it's clicked, and setting it when the page loads

Comment: localStorage is what are you looking for, show what you have tried. SessionStorage is not good becausewhen tab, window or browsers closes it get lost

Comment: Actually what do you mean by localStorage and sessionStorage?

Comment: Here's what I tried, it's the first time I've read of localStorage and I tried to follow the W3 Schools or Mozilla Developer Articles and apply it to my function....
`function greenButton() {

localStorage.setItem("bg", "white");

 document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem("bg");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}`

Answer (score 1):

As you are new to javascript I am using pure javascript for you here

create new function and call it on load of page like

```
<body onload="checkthelastColor()">
    <div class="green" onclick="greenButton()>green</div>
    <div class="red" onclick="redButton()>red</div>
    <div class="container">Content</div>
</body>
```

Here is the function

```
function checkthelastColor(){
    var color = localStorage.getItem("selectedColor")
    if(color == "red"){
        redButton()
    }else{
        greenButton()
    }
}
```

In your old functions save color in localStorage like

```
function greenButton() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    localStorage.setItem("selectedColor","green");
}
function redButton() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.backgroundColor = "black";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    localStorage.setItem("selectedColor","red");
}
```

Comment: @JuanMendes yes, sorry for that, but user may be not much good in javascript. I'll take care it next time.